# Disabling quick settings and notifications bar in Lollipop

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, root-access, 5.1-lollipop, notification-bar, quick-settings

I need to disable the quick settings and notifications bar on an Android Lollipop rooted device. The only way I've been able to do it is disabling the SystemUI app using the following command `pm disable com.android.systemui`. Is there any other way to do it that doesn't require installing any apps like Xposed? Maybe modifying .prop files or editing settings on .db?

Anyone knows how does Xposed-Gravity do it?

Comment: Does GravityBox do it? I only know that it _hides_ notification bar with Expanded Desktop.

Comment: Try GravityBox to remove all quick settings including the brightness slider. Try [Notifications Off](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aboutmycode.NotificationsOff&hl=en) to disallow all apps from showing a notification. If any app still shows up, explicitly disallow it using `appops` command.The solution is close, but not exactly what you need.